# Vuetify How add <br> to v-text-field error-messages

Tags: vuetify.js

I want to display new line, I use tag but not work.

The original idea was to new a component, and then customize error-messages to div, But it’s too much trouble, so come to ask if there is an easy way

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify);

var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
  methods: {
  },
  data: {
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.3/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.14.8/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.14.8/dist/vuetify.min.css">

<div id="app">
<v-app dark>
      <v-text-field
         label="Field"
          error-messages="aaa<br>bbb"
      ></v-text-field>
        
        
</v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Comment: Is it only <br> you need or other HTML tags too?

Comment: @GerryMM88 other HTML tags better :) have other way ?

Comment: @newer Sorry. I have never seen it solved with HTML-tags that way. You can build a custom validation, thats the only option I can think of.

Comment: @GerryMM88 Thank you very much for your suggestion, I guess so too, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a possible solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/ue9rqcwk/

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
<v-app dark>
      <v-text-field
      class="multiline"
         label="Field"
          error-messages="aaa
          bbb"
      ></v-text-field>
        
        
</v-app>
</div>
```

css:

```
.multiline {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

EDIT: Corrected URL